# Hey, I am trying to create a database of phone where volunteers can enter their detail but I want that anyone should not change someone else data

Tags: open-source, database

I tried Google docs but if I enters my phone number and other info I want others to be able to add their own number and other info. But if I share link either they can only view, comment or edit.
I don't want them to be able to edit my info. I just want them to add their info